# How to export vector tiles from a PostGIS raster database?

Tags: postgis, raster, openlayers

I have a PostGIS raster database with 5 tables loaded from 5 geoTIFF images, tiled 100x100. I am trying to setup a map tile server to display this data on an openlayers map. I need to transform the raster data into geometries and then export as vector tiles. I have the following query to select the data expecting a geometry:

```
WITH 
            bounds AS (
                SELECT ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, 3857),seg_size) AS geom, 
                       ST_Segmentize(ST_MakeEnvelope(xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, 3857),seg_size)::box2d AS b2d
            ),
            mvtgeom AS (
                SELECT ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_Transform({some_geom}, 3857), bounds.b2d) AS geom, 
                       gid, name, type
                FROM table t, bounds
                WHERE ST_Intersects({some_geom}, ST_Transform(bounds.geom, 3857))
            ) 
            SELECT ST_AsMVT(mvtgeom.*) FROM mvtgeom
```

How can I get the correct slice of the raster to input as a geometry into this query? I know I can use `ST_PixelsAsPolygons` to get polygons from the individual pixels, but how can I bound the data and give that query what it needs?

I tried adding:

```
fullrast AS (SELECT ST_Union(rast) As rast FROM table),
rast_clip AS (
    SELECT ST_Clip(fullrast, 1,
        bounds.geom)),
```

But it looks like the unioned raster exceeds the size limit:
`ERROR:  invalid memory alloc request size 18446744072322304320`

Comment: Vector pixels would be extremely inefficient. Why don't you use raster tiles?

Comment: @CL. We were hoping for a simple solution that didn't involve maintaining something like mapserver or geoserver. However, it looks like the only way to export tiles using PostGIS is in a vector format. You think this would be much less performant than using something like geoserver?

Comment: It would be *much* slower in every step of the pipeline, and the image quality would be worse.

Comment: @CL. What about exporting as images using something like ST_AsPNG? Obviously I'm still having the issue of having to somehow merge the tiles before cutting the bounds, but could this be more performant than converting to geometries?

Comment: That would work. But you should not merge rasters that do not overlap the requested tile.